# How to add animation inside a image in qt studio

Tags: qt, user-interface, animation

I have an image attached below, of a machine and I want to add those arrows and the tank filling and getting the empty type of animation using Qt studio but I don't know as I am new to Qt studio
Any help would be really helpful

[image]

Comment: Actually, you want one project :) In Qt For using Animation, I suggest you read [this DOC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html) ,
If you are writing one software you should paint that image with `QPainter`, then to add animation you should use that document.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.